# Embedding javascript within php code

Tags: javascript, php, client-side, server-side, embedding

I have embedded some javascript within php code. This was necessary after checking some php session variable value, and upon result, I use some JS within php to decide if some elements will be shown or not. Here is an example:

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['myVar']==2)
      { echo '<script type="text/javascript" >

          document.getElementById("element1").style.visibility = "hidden";
         document.getElementById("element2").style.visibility = "hidden";

            </script>';
?>
```

The code works perfect for me.
My question is : is the JS executed at the webserver(since it is embedded within php code) , initializing the page before it is sent to the client browser (and that what I think), or does the php portion run at the server, and the JS runs at the client later??

I know in normal situations the JS runs at the client browser,but was suspicious in this case,

I'm a junior programmer and any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: never combine server-side and client-side scripting. I have worst experiences doing so. If you really want to use PHP in clientside validations, Use AJAX calls and get JSON from PHP to use in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is **always** executed in the browser of the client. The php code just inserts the javascript code as a block of text and the browser reads it as code.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is executed on client-side no matter what, but your PHP code you just inserted the code to make it available for the browser to execute it...

Answer (score 1):

Php sends the JavaScript back to the Client as a response and then on the Client side JavaScript is run.
Please read this ANSWER 123 and you might have a better explanation >> [PHP & Embedded JavaScript Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['myVar']==2)
      { 
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
      document.getElementById("element1").style.visibility = "hidden";
         document.getElementById("element2").style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is not answering the question of @the4thDimension.